# Error after inline data of SELECT: "does not contain a structure..."

Tags: abap

I've got the error

> The dataobject "SYMBOL_DAT" does not contain a structure and therefore no component called "ATINN".

See code below, with the line in error marked.

Why does it work in the first loop but not in the second?

```
*"----------------------------------------------------------------------
*"*"Lokale Schnittstelle:
*"  IMPORTING
*"     REFERENCE(IT_MERKMALE) TYPE  ZEX_TECH_MERKMAL_TAB
*"  EXPORTING
*"     REFERENCE(ET_MERKMALE) TYPE  ZEX_TECH_MERKMAL_TAB
*"----------------------------------------------------------------------
DATA:
      LS_TECH_MERKMAL TYPE ZEX_TECH_MERKMAL.

SELECT SYMBOL_ID, INSTANCE
         FROM  V_IBINVALUES_F
         FOR ALL ENTRIES IN @IT_MERKMALE

         WHERE INSTANCE = @IT_MERKMALE-CUOBJ
         INTO @DATA(value_dat).

  SELECT ATINN
           FROM  IBSYMBOL
           WHERE SYMBOL_ID = @value_dat-SYMBOL_ID
           INTO @DATA(symbol_dat).

    CLEAR LS_TECH_MERKMAL.

    LS_TECH_MERKMAL-CUOBJ = value_dat-INSTANCE.
    LS_TECH_MERKMAL-ATINN = symbol_dat-ATINN.      "<===== error on this line
    APPEND LS_TECH_MERKMAL TO ET_MERKMALE.

  ENDSELECT.

ENDSELECT.
```

Comment: You should use Eclipse ADT because pressing F2 on `SYMBOL_DAT` would immediately show its type, which is of type `IBSYMBOL-ATINN` and not a structure (it works even if the program is not compiled yet).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would work, but you are selecting only the single field atinn into symbol_dat, so it really does not contain a structure.

Changing the inner assignment should fix your code:

`LS_TECH_MERKMAL-ATINN = symbol_dat.  “ hold the -atinn`

Let me add that doing SELECT ... ENDSELECT is bad from a performance perspective because it needs to perform a series of database round trips instead of retrieving all records in one go. Performing a nested SELECT ... ENDSELECT is even worse.

Comment: Thank you! Got it.

I actually started without using ENDSELECT:
Select into a table, loop through the table selecting the ATINN and appending it to a new table.
But I have no clue to to get the CUOBJ from the first select into the table with the ATINN.

Comment: I guess SELECT ATINN, ( @value-INSTANCE ) AS CUOBJ could work

Comment: @OmatoSoup You might want to look into how to perform a JOIN in a SELECT. It allows you to do exactly that on the database: Get results from table A and then the results of table B which have some value in common with those results from B.

Answer (score 1):

In the first loop you select several table fields. So the inline data declaration generates a structure with two fields( symbol_id and instance). In the second loop you select just one field( atinn ), therefore the inline data declaration does not generate a structure, instead, the selected value is directly copied to single variable symbol_dat. hence symbol_dat is just a simple variable and cannot be treated as a structure. And as @Florian has told you above, SELECT ... ENDSELECT is a bad coding practice( even worse to nest them ). Very slow due to multiple accesses to DB layer.